# Where is Python interpreter on Mac?

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv

I installed Python 3.5 and virtualenv using Homebrew. `python3` symlink in `/usr/local/bin` points to `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/bin/python3`, which means that when we execute a .py script using command `python3`, then the interpreter in the location above will be used.

But, when I see the contents of virtualenv in `/usr/local/bin` using `cat virtualenv`, the shebang is `#!/usr/local/opt/python3/bin/python3.5`, which means that when we execute `virtualenv`, then interpreter in `/usr/local/opt` is used.

Why is there a difference in the python interpreter being used? Which one should be used?

Comment: You can see all interpreters using `which -a python3`. You can specify an interpreter for a `virtualenv` when you create it with the `-p` flag. You can use whichever is appropriate for your project,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely, `/usr/local/opt/python3` is a symlink actually pointing to `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.0/bin/python3`. `ls -l /usr/local/opt/python3` will show what it's pointing to.

To my knowledge, OSX doesn't have anything installed natively in `/usr/local/opt/` without homebrew.

Also, OSX doesn't come with python3.